# spring integration vs reactive-streams

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-xd, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I'm working on an ETL project. I've been using spring integration for a long time. The data source is currently files or chronicle but it may change to live streams and volumes are likely to grow. There is a potential to move on to big data solutions (hadoop, spark etc) in the future.

Based on this I need a comparison between spring integration and reactive streams? Why would anyone use one over the other (or am I wrong in the first place trying to compare the two)? Scenarios (if any) where you think they could be used together?

Comment: For inspiration of using Reactive Streams for integration workloads, have a look at Alpakka: http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/
(disclaimer: I work for Lightbend)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both of them can be used together. Check out the documentation for [Reactive Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/reactive-streams.html).